# Inclusion of affine algebraic sets - converse direction

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ideals

Let $I, J \subseteq K[x_0, \dotsc, x_n ]$ with $I \subseteq J$, then I have $V(J) \subseteq V(I)$ (looking at it from the affine space).

Now I was wondering whether also the converse direction holds, i.e. for $V(J) \subseteq V(I)$, I can deduce that $I \subseteq J$?

So far, I've always only seen it stated in one direction.

It would be great if anybody could tell whether or under which circumstances also the other directions holds. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The converse is not necessarily true. Consider the ideals $$J=((x-1)(x-2)^2),~I=((x-1)(x-2)(x-3))\subseteq K[x]$$

Then $$V(J)=\{1,2\}\subset V(I)=\{1,2,3\}$$ but $$I\not\subset J$$

I think you can also see why this is a problem, it's because of $(x-2)^2$, the square. It doesn't change the set of roots, but it makes the ideal smaller.

What is true, is that if $K$ is algrebraically closed, then $$V(J)\subseteq V(I)\rightarrow \sqrt I\subseteq\sqrt J$$ because then we have no square factors. This can be proven using [Hilbert's Nullstellensatz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_Nullstellensatz).

Indeed, $\sqrt J=((x-1)(x-2))$ and $\sqrt I=((x-1)(x-2)(x-3))$, so $$\sqrt I\subseteq \sqrt J$$

---

An even simpler counter-example:

Consider the special case in which $V(I)=V(J)$ (that is $V(I)\subseteq V(J)$ and $V(J)\subseteq V(I)$), if the conserve was true this would imply $J\subseteq I$ and $I\subseteq J$, that is, $I=J$. Now take $$I=(x-1)^2,~J=(x-1)\subseteq K[x]$$

$V(I)=V(J)$, but $I\neq J$.

Comment: What is wrong with the original example?

Comment: @KennyLau I don't follow you, which example?

Comment: the $((x-1)^2)$ and $((x-1))$ example

Comment: @KennyLau I don't know, is there something wrong with it? Not sure I understand what you mean, I meant to say that one of the things that make the inclusion fail is that you can make the ideal smaller and smaller by raising it's power, without changing the zero-set.

Comment: Well if there's nothing wrong then why did you delete it and change the answer?

Comment: @KennyLau Ah, now I see what you mean! Yes, I deleted the answer because I thought I misread the question, also, I wanted $V(I), V(J)$ with strict inclusion. Otherwise, OP's question would imply $V(I)=V(J)\Rightarrow I=J$, which is a little bit boring.

Comment: Restrict the ideals to radical ideals, i.e., $I=\sqrt I$.